# Proof explanation, covariance operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, proof-explanation

In the book Gaussian Measures by Bogachev, Theorem 2.3.1 he shows that if $\mu$ is a Gaussian measure on a separable Hilbert space, then its characteristic functional is given by
$$\hat\mu(x)=e^{-i(a,x)-\frac{(Kx,x)}{2}}$$
where $a \in X$ is a vector and $K$ is a symmetric non negative nuclear operator.
To show that $K$ is compact, he says

> If $x_n\to 0$ in the weak topology, then $\hat\mu(x)\to 1$ by Lebesgue's theorem. Hence $\|\sqrt{K}x_n\|\to 0$

I don't see how this shows $K$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

It tells us that on a separable Hilbert (or just reflexive) space the unit ball with the weak topology is metrizable and compact.

Observe that the quoted line implies that the operator $L:=\sqrt{K}$ restricted to the closed unit ball $B_X$ is weak-to-norm continuous as $B_X$ is metrizable. But then $L(B_X)$ is norm compact as $B_X$ is weakly compact. Hence, $L$ is compact and $K=L^2$ is compact as well.

Comment: So $x_n$ converging to 0 weakly mean all continuous linear functionals and hence $\hat\mu(x)$ converges to $\hat\mu(0)=1$ so I only need to show the square root of $K$ is symmetric and and I'm done since that exponent is precisely $\lim\|Lx_n\|^2$. Am I correct in my reasoning

Comment: @badatmath I think you need to show that $K$, rather than $\sqrt{K}$, is symmetric non negative in order to show that $\sqrt{K}$ even exists. Aside from this, yes.

Comment: If K is symmetric bounded non negative then its self adjoined and non negative and has a self adjoined square root @Keeper

Comment: @badatmath Yes :)